# Tikzcd: shifted diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd

Using `tikzcd` I have the problem that, when inserting diagrams in a text part, like:

```
Blah Blah Blah [tikz diagram] blah
```

Then it will end to be graphically shifted upon a little bit, like in these examples:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to fix centering the diagram?

Here the options that I am using for the document

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
```

And Here the code of the first diagram:

```
\begin{tikzcd} 
\mathcal{R} \ar[r,shift left, "s" above]
            \ar[r,shift right,"t" below]
   & X \\
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why you think that giving separate document preamble and document content is  better suited than one document which we can copy and compile? Please merge them into one file ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the final `\\` which has nothing to do here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

And Here the code of the first diagram:
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathcal{R} \ar[r,shift left, "s" above]
            \ar[r,shift right,"t" below]
   & X
\end{tikzcd}%

\end{document}
```

[image]